# Thrust vectorized search: Efficiently combine lower_bound and binary_search to find both position and existence

Tags: search, cuda, binary-search, thrust, lower-bound

I'm trying to use Thrust to detect if each element of an array can be found in another array and where (both arrays are sorted). I came across the vectorized search routines (lower_bound and binary_search).

lower_bound will return for each value the index where it could be inserted in a list respecting its ordering.

I also need to know if the value is found or not (which can be done with binary_search), not just its position.

Is it possible to achieve both efficiently without making two searches (calling binary_search and then lower_bound)?

I know in the scalar case, lower_bound will return a pointer to end of the array if a value cannot be found, but this does not happens in the vectorized version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check that the element that `lower_bound` returns is the same as the one you searched for. E.g. given `a = {1,3,5}` and searching for `b = {1,4}`, the result will be `c = {0,2}`. We have `a[c[0]] == b[0]`, so `b[0]` is in `a`, but `a[c[1]] != b[1]` so `b[1]` is not in `a`.

(Note that you will need to ensure that you don't make any out-of-bounds memory accesses, since `lower_bound` can return an index that is beyond the end of the array.)

Answer (score 0):

@tat0: you can also play around with [Arrayfire](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/):
vectorized search using lower_bound() does not give you the answer immediately
while with setintersect() in arrayfire, you get the "intersection" of two arrays directly:

```
float A_host[] = {3,22,4,5,2,9,234,11,6,17,7,873,23,45,454};
int szA = sizeof(A_host) / sizeof(float); 

float B_host[] = {345,5,55,6,7,8,19,2,63}; 
int szB = sizeof(B_host) / sizeof(float); 

// initialize arrays from host data
array A(szA, 1, A_host);
array B(szB, 1, B_host);

array U = setintersect(A, B); // compute intersection of 2 arrays

int n_common = U.elements();
std::cout << "common: ";     
print(U);
```

the output is:
common: U = 2.0000 
           5.0000 
           6.0000 
           7.0000

to get the actual locations of these elements in array A, you can use the following 
construct (provided that elements in A are unique):

```
int n_common = U.elements();
array loc = zeros(n_common); // empty array      

gfor(array i, n_common) // parallel for loop
     loc(i) = sum((A == U(i))*seq(szA));
print(loc);
```

then: loc =
           4.0000 
           3.0000 
           8.0000 
          10.0000

Furthermore, thrust::lower_bound() seems to be slower than setintersect(), 
i benchmarked it with the following program:

```
int *g_data = 0;
int g_N = 0;

void thrust_test() {
 thrust::device_ptr<int> A = thrust::device_pointer_cast((int *)g_data),
     B = thrust::device_pointer_cast((int *)g_data + g_N);
 thrust::device_vector<int> output(g_N);
 thrust::lower_bound(A, A + g_N, B, B + g_N, 
                  output.begin(),
                  thrust::less<int>());
 std::cout << "thrust: " << output.size() << "\n";
}
void af_test() 
{   
  array A(g_N, 1, g_data, afDevicePointer);
  array B(g_N, 1, g_data + g_N, afDevicePointer);
  array U = setintersect(A, B);
  std::cout << "intersection sz: " << U.elements() << "\n";
}
int main()
{
  g_N = 3e6; // 3M entries
  thrust::host_vector< int > input(g_N*2);
  for(int i = 0; i < g_N*2; i++) {  // generate some input
    if(i & 1)
       input[i] = (i*i) % 1131;
    else
       input[i] = (i*i*i-1) % 1223 ;
 }
 thrust::device_vector< int > dev_input = input;
 // sort the vector A
 thrust::sort(dev_input.begin(), dev_input.begin() + g_N);
 // sort the vector B
 thrust::sort(dev_input.begin() + g_N, dev_input.begin() + g_N*2);
 g_data = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dev_input.data());
 try {
    info();
    printf("thrust:  %.5f seconds\n", timeit(thrust_test));
    printf("af:  %.5f seconds\n", timeit(af_test));
 } catch (af::exception& e) {
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
 }
return 0;
}
```

and the results:

CUDA toolkit 4.2, driver 295.59

GPU0 GeForce GT 650M, 2048 MB, Compute 3.0 (single,double)

Memory Usage: 1937 MB free (2048 MB total)

thrust:  0.13008 seconds

arrayfire:  0.06702 seconds